# Trying to fake new geometry using the normal/AO/diffuse maps of an existing model used in Unity without modifying the underlying asset's mesh in game

Tags: normal-map, ambient-occlusion

So, I am currently trying to make an advanced custom skin for the game Rust.  Rust is built in Unity. So my current workflow is to apply materials as I want, then I use cycles to bake the Normal, Ambient Occlusion, Diffuse and Emission maps.

So far this works great for simple modifications.  However, I want to modify the geometry of the base mesh, apply texture & materials to it, then bake as normal.   Say I want to encrust a jewel in the surface of a wooden box, in a normal game environment, I'd modify the mesh and apply textures etc.  However, in this case, as I'm making a skin for a game, I do not have the liberty to modify the mesh directly.  Though I can fake a lot of it via Normal/AO maps.

My question is what is the best workflow to use here?  I am currently thinking of using a cage, creating a modified 'high poly' the way I want, then applying materials and textures and using a cage approach to bake from high-to-low.  I am still new to this workflow and wanted to make sure that this approach works for all maps needed (Normal, AO, Diffuse, Emission).  Also, will I need to boolean union my union's to the highpoly or does doing a simple join operation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>J</kbd>) suffice?

TLDR;
I want to "encrust" a jewel onto the surface of a box, and then bake all of the maps *without* relying on modifying the in-game mesh, but still faking the lighting and shininess etc.

Here's an example of a modified box:

[image]

Here's the original box for reference:

[image]

Comment: You can copy an image and Ctrl + V right into the editor to post an image to stackexchange's imgur

Comment: Whether you need a cage depends on the exact high poly/low poly relationship.  Joining or booleaning depends on your needs-- you won't get smooth shaded connections with joined geometry, while you may with booleaning (but it will probably require some cleanup.)  Yes, you'll use the same high poly and cage for all maps.  Low polys are generally made *after* the high poly, and there are limits to how much you can get away with, without changing the low poly.

Comment: @AllenSimpson - thanks I gotch'ya.

Comment: @Nathan - thanks for the clear response. Does this mean the edges of the meshes being joined won't have any negative impact on the baked images (aka. where there's some of the outer mesh inside the inner mesh? Also, does this mean my approach would be considered best practice here, or should I consider something different?